# javascript - window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can I concatenate ID from database and URL?

This is my code. I have an error "The server tag is not well formed."

```
NavigateUrl="javascript:void(window.open('ChangeHistory.aspx?ID="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>" ','_blank','height=600','width=600') );"
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you need:

```
NavigateUrl="javascript:void(window.open('ChangeHistory.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>','_blank','height=600','width=600') );"
```

That is, remove the `"` that was just before `<%` and the one from just after `>%`.

Comment: Try `<%=` or `<%$` instead of `<%#` (in addition to what I said in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the `NavigateUrl` Attribute from server side code...it will be very easy and also to include your `ID` in `window.open` method.

if it's in some `Grid/Repeater/Datalist` then use the `DataBound` property otherwise use `Page_Load` event to add attribute to it...

Example

```
Foocontrol.NavigateUrl=@"javascript:void(window.open
     ('ChangeHistory.aspx? ID='"+YourID+"','_blank','height=600','width=600') )";
```

**Edit**

```
protected void yourGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     HyperLink hlnkViewHistory = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlnkViewHistory");
     hlnkViewHistory.NavigateUrl==@"javascript:void(window.open
     ('ChangeHistory.aspx? ID='"+YourID+"','_blank','height=600','width=600') )";
   }
 }
```

YourID - add your ID whatever you want to send as parameter....

Comment: this is my code. it is a column inside datagrid. <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkViewHistory" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsModified") %>' Enabled="True" Text="View History"
         NavigateUrl="javascript:void(window.open('ChangeHistory.aspx?ID='+'<%# Eval("id") %>+ ','_blank','height=600','width=600') )" >
       </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: why don't you add `Navigateurl` property of `RowDataBound` event of grid...that would be much easier for you..

Comment: there is no RowDataBound event in datagrid

Comment: Gridview has a event `RowDataBound`, It may you haven't used yet...see Data Grid events here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid_events.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have changed this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ChangeHistory.aspx?id={0}", Eval("id")) %>' onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'DownloadImage','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;">Open</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: is there any other way? without calling a function?

Comment: Iam using this.. still Now didnt checked alternative. Why? Is there any problem?